# How do I specify language when storing strings?

Tags: localization, internationalization

I'm currently developing a system that supports several languages. I want to specify these languages as precisely as possible in the database in case of future integrations. (Yes I know it's a bit YAGNI)

I've found several ways to define a language

- `nb-NO`
- `nb_NO`
- `nb-no`
- `nb_no`
- `nb`

These can all mean "Norwegian Bokmål". Which one, if any, is the most correct?

The [Locale](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale) article on the ArchLinux Wiki specifies a Locale as `language[_territory][.codeset][@modifier]`. The `codeset` and `modifier` I guess are only relevant for input. But `language` is a minimum and `territory` may be nice to have should we implement cultural differences regarding currency and decimal points etc.

Am I overthinking it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at BCP 47
https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47

In this day and age you would need at to support at least language, script, region (only language being mandatory to be present)

It depends a lot what you use this tags for.
If it is spoken content you might care about dialect (for instance Cantonese vs Mandarin Chinese), but not script. In written form you will care about script (Traditional vs. Simplified Chinese), but not dialect.

It also matters a lot the complete stack you use to process things. You might use minus as separator, use grandfathered ids, or the -u- extension (see bcp,) then discover that you use a programming language that "chokes" on it. Or you use "he" for Hebrew, but your language (cough Java cough) wants the deprecated "iw"

So you might decide to use the same locale id as your tech stack, or have a "conversion layer".
If you want things accessible from several technologies, then conversion layers is your only (reasonable) option.